# \gls Doesn't seem to work in memoir as all my Glossary terms are capitalized

Tags: memoir, glossaries

I want to include lowercase terms within a sentence but the `\gls` doesn't seem to work in memoir class. I found elsewhere that memoir doesn't have the gls command but is there an alternative if you're using `\usepackage{glossaries}`?

maintext

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[style = british]{csquotes}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}                                                   %
\graphicspath{ {Documents/PhD/Thesis/figures/} }
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
\settocdepth{subsection}

\usepackage{epigraph}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc,acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\setlength\epigraphwidth{1\textwidth}
\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt} % no line between
\setlength\beforeepigraphskip{1\baselineskip} % space before and after epigraph
\setlength\afterepigraphskip{2\baselineskip}
\renewcommand*{\textflush}{flushright}
\renewcommand*{\epigraphsize}{\normalsize\itshape}


\addto\captionsUKenglish{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0em}{\bf\LARGE}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}

\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\AtEveryBibitem{
    \clearfield{month}
    \clearfield{day}
    \clearfield{urlyear}
    \clearfield{urlmonth}
}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  bibliography = {References}
}


\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\input{front_matter}

\mainmatter
\input{Chapters/chapter01}
\input{Chapters/chapter02}
\input{Chapters/chapter03}
\input{Chapters/chapter04}
\input{Chapters/chapter05}
```

And this is what I use in my acronym.txt

```
\newglossaryentry{communication}
{       name=Communication,
        description={A simultaneous selection of information, utterance, and understanding}
}

\newglossaryentry{system}
{
        name=System,
        description={A whole that is comprised of parts, but not necessarily reducible to them}
}

\newglossaryentry{dissemination_media}
{
        name=Dissemination Media,
        description={Media that extends communication in space and time}
}






\newacronym{sst}{SST}{Social Systems Theory}

\newacronym{dss}{DSS}{Digital Social System}





\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\printglossary`

\printbibliography
\input{appendix}
\end{document}`
```

Comment: I tried to compile your MWE but could not as it included many files that you did not provide, like `chapter01`. Also much in your MWE had nothing to do with glossaries. How is `acronym.txt` used?  `memoir` does nothing about glossaries, that's all up to the `glossaries` package which does define the `gls` macro. I have never tried making a glossary. I hope someone knowledgeable about `glossaries` can help you. --- GOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by not using all of the fields of `\newglossaryentry`, if you use just `name=` with the capital letter then it will always appear, use the entry named `text=` in lowercase so that `\gls` and `\Gls` can work properly. I condensed your code down into this which is more minimal then the code you posted:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc,acronym]{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{communication}
{       name={Communication},
        text={communication},
        description={A simultaneous selection of information, utterance, and understanding}
}

\newacronym{sst}{SST}{Social Systems Theory}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
This is the acronym \gls{sst}.

This is lowercase \gls{communication}.

This is uppercase \Gls{communication}.
\end{document}
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

As an aside, I always put `\makeglossaries` after the glossary entries have been defined, `biblatex` should be loaded before `hyperref` (indeed most packages should except for `glossaries`, `cleverref` etc.) and in the future, please check with how to make a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/245306) so it is easier to help. I understand you are new so do not worry this time but for example, your code will not compile as we do not have access to your `\input{chapters\chapter01}` files etc.

I am attaching a template I made from the documentation and other websites (including [Dickimaw Books](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/html/makeglossaries.html)) which contains all of the glossaries options, maybe it will assist you:

```
%----- Using glossary entries in text

%\gls[options including hyperbf to bold the entry]{in-text \gls name}[text to inset afterwards within the hyperlink]
%\glspl{same as above but plural}
%\Gls{same as above but capital singular}
%\Glspl{same as above capital plural}

%----- \newglossary template

% \newglossary[extension for log]{name of glossary}{input extension}{output extension}{title of glossary for printglossary}

%----- Glossary entry template with all fields

%\newglossaryentry{in-text \gls name}
%   {%
%   name={name that appears in glossary},
%   description={description that appears in glossary},
%   text={in-text where singular form required, if not defined uses name}
%   first={first time used with singular form, if not defined uses text},
%   plural={plural form, if not defined adds s to text value},
%   firstplural={first time plural used},
%   symbols={adds a symbol if needed},
%   sort={how to sort entry},
%   type={glossary name that this entry belongs to},
%   }

%----- Print glossary template

%\printglossary[type={first {} of \newglossary},
%         style={style name from \newglossarystyle},
%         title={Override title with new one here},
%         toctitle={TOC title},
%         numberedsection,      % Puts glossary in numbered section
%         nonumberlist,     % Suppress location lists for glossary
%         ]
```

I typically define `text`, `first` and `firstplural` although whatever suits your needs best. Hope your thesis is going smoothly.

Comment: This was superbly helpful. Thank you kindly! I've been doing my own formatting in order to better understand LaTeX, but I couldn't figure out the Glossary issue (I think my head is overwhelmed with the thesis). I used your code but the issue actually persisted, so I started a new doc with your code and input line-by-line to see what wasn't working. But after copying every line of code, the \gsl command ended up working. Not sure what the issue was but at least it works now!